# Get focus status out of application in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi

I'm trying to create an android-like keyboard in Delphi that appears when a textbox is in focus. I need to know some way to get this status of focus in all the programs so I can give a show in my form and send it forward

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Why not?

Comment: @Anders: Because I incorrectly assumed the OP wanted to create an Android keyboard. But after reading the Q one more time, I realise the OP actually wants to create a Win32 application.

Answer (score 0):

[`SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) to register for focus changes. Once you know the window you check the class name for "Edit" and you can get the thread id and then get caret information from `GetGUIThreadInfo` if you need that...

Comment: What about Rich Edit controls?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand The OP can check for whatever class names they are interested in.

Comment: If looking at class names, be sure to take `Real­Get­Window­Class()` into account. See [What makes RealGetWindowClass so much more real than GetClassName?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101231-00/?p=11863)